# Putting electronics in sand to keep them cool?

Tags: heat

I am running some RTL-SDR software defined radio USB dongles.  They have metal cases, and can get pretty hot.  I saw it mentioned that they can be cooled down by burying them in sand.  Since i won't need to touch them after they're set up, is this a good way to go?

I could attach a heat sink to each of them but it would require some work (cutting, etc.)

Comment: I have never heard of putting them in sand as a cooling method. Sand is a very poor thermal conductor, I would expect it to be more of a insulator, keeping the heat in the unit than pulling the heat out. Hence bad. Assuming these are off-the-shelf parts, it would be fair to assume that they are designed to get hot without failing, so you don't need to cool them.

Comment: I'd suggest airflow instead. You may be able to attach stick-on heatsinks to the metal case, too.

Comment: I think you need to go back to where you saw that and look at the context. Burying something in sand might help to keep it cool *in the desert*, but not if its producing any significant heat of its own.

Comment: Already the thermal resistance going from the chip to the plastic casing is going to be so bad, that there lies your best opportunity: remove the case, provide some cooling directly on the chip. And yes, they get hot, but they are designed that way.

Answer (score 4):

Sand is a pretty good thermal conductor (k=0.2) compared to air (k=0.02)and good clean silica sand is an excellent electrical insulator.  Vegetable Oil or mineral oil is about the same used for transformer cooling (k=0.3)  . and only has a dielectric constant of 2... but messy if your case leaks.

But forced air can improve thermal resistance by 60% or more depending on surface area+ roughness with just a low velocity of 3m/s just over a large flat area or a heatsink. (my own test results)

The limitation of heat transfer could possible be to the outside surface area for cooling the sand thru the case but it would do well in spreading the heat.

As an example of heat transfer, I recall seeing a youtube video of middle eastern coffee brewed with extra fine coffee in a small BBQ container filled with sand.   The aluminum pot for   a few small cups takes several minutes on a 2kW stove top.

But when the small thin pot is dipped in propane heated sand pit, it takes only one half a second until it foams up., which is great for mass production at an expresso party.

Although it might be worth trying, I would use fins with a 30 mm fan. :)

Answer (score 3):

Sand is a better heat conductor than air (like an order of magnitude better), but with sand you negate the effect of convection which might cool the device more than the conduction of the sand. (this might be an interesting research)

If the device comes as a module like that and has no specifics on cooling, I'd expect it to run fine in normal conditions (up to 35°C air temperature or something).

Thinking of an USB dongle with an antenna connector and sand just made me imagine how small particles end up in all those connectors which you will probably take apart and put together at some point. The scratching noises make my hair stand up even before you've done it (yeah you said you don't need to touch them, but things change).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bad idea to me.  Sand is a temperature INSULATOR, not a conductor.  You would end up CONCENTRATING heat right where you don't want to.

"Hot" isn't necessarily "bad".  If you can still touch it, and keep your finger on it, it probably isn't too hot to function correctly.

Comment: I think you mean "thermal" insulator (not temperature). It's not going to concentrate the heat - that's already concentrated at the source - but will contain it and reduce dissipation.

Comment: Also, "hot" is a problem for things where accuracy of an oscillator is an issue, which is the case here.

Comment: But then, why exist sand-cemented resistors?